# Grub cannot find ntfs.mod

Tags: linux, windows, grub, ntfs

I am not able to boot into my Windows partition.
When startig grub and entering windows it just shows the text on the Grub Windows Boot picture.

grub.d/40_custom:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' --class windows --class os{
  insmod ntfs
  insmod chain
  set root='(hd0,1)'
  chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

[Grub Windows Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeUA4.png)

Comment: copy the text and paste here, not in images

Comment: post output of **locate ntfs.mod**

Comment: @Cestarian `/boot/grub/i386-pc/ntfs.mod
                    /boot/grub.bak/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod
                    /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/ntfs.mod`

Comment: Hmm it's clearly there... I assume you're using x86_64-efi grub. I haven't dual-booted for years though, never with Windows 10, so I'm not sure how to solve this though I have some theories... maybe try running grub-mkconfig again? In the meantime, I think you should be able to boot into windows from your UEFI bios, to circumvent the bootloader altogether.

Comment: @Cestarian I am able to boot into windows, should I send you the mkconfig?

Comment: Using xfs as the base file system by any chance? https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,5952.0.html